# Google CSE - instead of redirecting to a page from the results view can I display the page itself embedded on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-custom-search

I have a google CSE embedded that searches the entire web. Say, a user searches for "stackoverflow" he is displayed the **results** page **still ON MY SITE**, where "www.stackoverflow.com" is the first result and then there are some moew results, **but when he clicks on any of the results** the **page is opened in a new tab**.

What I would like to know is, how I could make it so that when any of the results are clicked the page it points to will instead of opening in new tab, be loaded in an iframe still within my site.

Also, could this be a legal issue?

Looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Found an the answer on how to do it, still don't know if it is legal.

But in order to open any of the results inside a iframe on your page, all you have to do is to add `linktarget="Name_of_your_iframe_here"` to the GCSE like this `<gcse:search linktarget="iframe_a"></gcse:search>`

I already tested few sites, and found out that most of the major websites have countermeasures in place that won't allow you to load them within an iframe, so it will be necessary to provide some fallback for those..